# Scrapy not able to get image url and also not able to download images

Tags: python, image, scrapy, pipeline

I have tried every search result in google and stack overflow solution but i am not able to get the solution.
I am creating a scrapy to extract images please find the code below

My items.py

```
class MyntraItem(scrapy.Item):
    product_urls=scrapy.Field()
    files=scrapy.Field()
    image_urls=scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
```

My settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'hello'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['myntra.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'myntra.spiders'

FILES_STORE = '/home/swapnil/Desktop/AI/myntra/'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   #'myntra.pipelines.SomePipeline': 300,   
   'scrapy.pipelines.images.FilesPipeline': 1,
}
```

My first.py

```
class FirstSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "first"
    allowed_domains = ["myntra.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.myntra.com/men-sports-tshirts-menu?src=tNav&f=Pattern_article_attr%3Astriped',
    ]
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=['//*[@class="product-link"]']),callback='parse_lnk',follow=True)]
    #rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['.*']),callback='parse_lnk',follow=True)]

    def parse_lnk(self, response):
        item=MyntraItem()
        item['product_urls']=response.url
        item['files']=response.xpath('//*[@class="thumbnails-selected-image"]/@src')
        item['image_urls']=item['files']
        #print '666666666666666666',item['files']
        return item
```

Please help: My intention is to download the images.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `FilesPipeline` expects file URLs to be available from the value of [an item's `"file_urls"` key](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#usage-example).

> (...) if a spider returns a dict with the URLs key (`"file_urls`" or
>   `"image_urls"`, for the Files or Images Pipeline respectively), the
>   pipeline will put the results under respective key (`"files"` or `"images"`).

It seems you are using `"product_urls"`. To change where the pipeline looks for URLs, you need to set `FILES_URLS_FIELD = "product_urls"`.

Comment: in my code 'product_urls' is all the product links not the image links and item['files']=response.xpath('//*[@class="thumbnails-selected-image"]/@src') this code has the info about the images needed to be downloaded, and as suggested by you to change the name with image_urls than also it doesnt work. Please check the updated code

Comment: I see. You're using `FilesPipeline`, so you need to either 1) use a `file_urls` field in your item definition, and populate it when returning items, or 2) tell the pipeline to look for another field, but your `settings.py` needs to define `FILES_URLS_FIELD = "images_urls"`. The alternative, with less change in your code, is to load the `ImagesPipeline` instead of `FilesPipeline`. Also note that `//*[@class="thumbnails-selected-image"]/@src` does not seem to yield images from product pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ImagesPipeline** instead, and extract the images using **regex**.

In My first.py

```
item['files']= re.findall('front":\{"path":"(.+?)"', response.body)
```

In settings.py

```
IMAGES_STORE = '/home/swapnil/Desktop/AI/myntra/'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {'myntra.pipelines.SomePipeline': 300,
                  'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1,}
```

This would works like a charm.

Comment: i tried your suggestion and then tried [link](http://www.myntra.com/tshirts/fila/fila-men-green-eagle-printed-round-neck-t-shirt/1502783/buy?src=search&uq=false&q=C%3A%2FUsers%2Fsharm_000%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Ftmpqshvkx.html&p=4) view this link in scrapy shell and it is not giving any body conteny may be this is an issue here.

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue, however, the images urls are actually stored in a javascript variable before it got rendered into the browser; so you need to extract the images urls either using the re method in **HtmlXPathSelector** or using **re** module directly.